# Retain the image loaded on canvas from photoalbum on click of Undo button

Tags: ios, uikit, drawing, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am working on drawing in IOS using `coregraphics`, So I draw an image on canvas and store in a photo ablum, later I load the same drawn image from photo Album on canvas using this piece of code

```
[imageFromAlbum drawnInRect:self.bounds];
```

this brings the image on canvas, Now I draw 2 lines on this image and click on undo, on first click  of undo, first line disappears, on second click of undo, remaining line along with image disappears, but I want that image not to disappear on click of undo.

How to solve this issue.

Edit based on below commnets. on click of undo I call this function

```
-(void)redrawLine
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 

    NSDictionary *lineInfo = [m_undoArray lastObject];
    m_curImage = [lineInfo valueForKey:@"IMAGE"];   
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];  
   drawstep = UNDO;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        case UNDO:
        {
            [m_curImage drawInRect:self.bounds];            
        }
            break;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how you are drawing the 2 lines, is it using UIBezierPath?

Comment: hi, no I am using Paths. using the functions CGContextMovetoPoint, CGCOntextAddLineToPoint

Comment: ok, how you are removing the lines during undo ?

Comment: Show us the whole drawing code

Comment: For undo functionality, as you all know, we have to maintain an undoarray, So on click of undo, I am removing that image from undo array and again calling the redraw function, which is above.

Comment: hey guys  any clue, you asked for code, I provided the code